# How to use logger statement in neo4j 3.0?

Tags: logging, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In earlier version of neo4j i was using **java.util.logging**

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(xxx.class.getName());
LOGGER.info("Server started");
```

This was logging the data to neo4j.0.0.log

If i use `System.out.println("Neo4j server started");`,logs were coming in console.log.  Now in 3.0.1 both methods are not working.

So how use logger to print something to log file?

Comment: How do you use neo4j? With an embedded graph database or standalone server? In my opinion this sort of logging to the neo4j's log files makes only sense if you are either writing an unmanaged extension/procedure or you are using an embedded version. Maybe you can give more detail information.